# cblas_dgemm segmentation faults on large matrices

Tags: c++, c, blas, intel-mkl

I am working on a 24 core machine, with ~400GB of memory, running Ubuntu.  I am encountering a segmentation fault when doing a simple matrix multiplication using Intel MKL cblas_dgemm:

```
  int k=5;
  int m=2E5;
  int n=3E4;
  double * A = (double *)mkl_malloc( m*k*sizeof( double ), 64 );
  UTILITIES::check_alloc("A", A); //Check alloc just checks if the pointer is null
  UTILITIES::random_matrix(m,k,A); //fills matrix with random numbers

  double * B = (double *)mkl_malloc( k*n*sizeof( double ), 64 );
  UTILITIES::check_alloc("B", B);
  UTILITIES::random_matrix(k,n,B); //files matrix with random numbers

  double * TestMatrix = (double *)mkl_malloc( m*n*sizeof( double ), 64 );
  printf("Allocating a matrix of size %le\n",(double) m*n*sizeof(double)); //4.8E10
  UTILITIES::check_alloc("TestMatrix", TestMatrix);//No problem

  for (int i=0; i<m*n; i++) { //I added this just to make sure I could allocate the memory, of course this will all be overwritten
    TestMatrix[i] = 1.0;
  }

  printf("TestMatrix %lf\n", TestMatrix[1]); //no problem accessing the memory

  cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, m,n,k,
      1.0,
      A,k,
      B,n,
      0.0,
      TestMatrix,n); //Segfaults at this line (without it, there is no segfault).
```

If I change the size of the matrices, to make n=1E4, there is no segmentation fault.

Do you have any thoughts?

Note that I have confirmed that I am compiling with 64 bits:

```
#if __x86_64__
  printf("Running 64 bit\n");
#endif
```

My compile line:

```
g++ -m64 main.cpp -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/include -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess would be `m*n` in your initialization `for` loop causes overflow.

However, (credit to mch) the segfault is due to overflow in `m*n*sizeof(double)`. Apparently `m*n` is evaluated before upcasted to `size_t`. One way to fix it is to change `m` and `n` to `long long`, and accordingly also `i`.

Comment: Do you mean integer overflow?  How is that possible on a 64 bit machine and compiling 64 bit?

Furthermore, the segfault does not occur without the matrix multiplication (and with the initialization).

Comment: You could check this, for instance by printing `INT_MAX` from `limits.h`

Comment: I checked, and m*n does not exceed INT_MAX (2147483647).  Regardless, I changed the initialization loop to long int, and we still segfault.  As I said though, even without initialization, there is still a segfault.

Comment: m*n is 6e9, which is 3 times larger than INT_MAX

Comment: @mch My mistake, yes it is bigger.  However, that does not solve the problem.  I assume that cblas_dgemm uses long int or something similar to index the array, does it not?  I believe I am using the 64 bit version of the library.

Comment: change `m`,`n` and `i` to `long long`, `long int`s size is only 4 byte

Comment: Wow, that was it.  The problem was not in the initialization for loop--it was in the malloc!  I was passing m*n*size(double), which overflowed, and did not allocate a full matrix.  By changing m,n to long long the problem was solved--but it is also solved by type casting the m*n*size(double) to long long.  Thank you!

Comment: Could one of you please edit the answer or make a new one so that I can accept it?  I think this could be very useful for future people, and the current answer we are commenting on is close, but not it.

Comment: did you also change `i` to `long long`? otherwise the for loop would be an endless loop @downhillFromHere you should also edit this into your answer

Comment: @mch I removed the initialization loop entirely, but if I had left it, I would have changed it as well, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
  cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, m,n,k,
      1.0,
      A,k,
      B,n,
      0.0,
      TestMatrix,n);
```

-----------------------------^ try changing to `m`

[From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/BLAS_Ref/Reference/reference.html), the last parameter:

> ldc
>
> The size of the first dimention of matrix C; if you are passing a
>   matrix C[m][n], the value should be m.

Comment: I tried it, and it still segfaults.

In C, it is Row Major, so the leading dimension should be the number of columns.  Perhaps the documentation you linked to is referring to column major?  Here is the documentation I used: https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/mkl/tutorials/mkl_mmx_c/index.htm